# NameError: name 'articles' is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm beginner in Django and I am having errors on my very first day. 
Can anyone help me?

Here is error I'm getting

> File "/home/akshay/Desktop/cdsmalpha/cdsmalpha/urls.py", line 23, in module>
>       url(r'^hello/', articles.views.hello, name = 'hello'),
>     NameError: name 'articles' is not defined

Here is my url.py file in main project directory

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from articles import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/', articles.views.hello, name = 'hello'),
]
```

Comment: Just do `views.hello` instead of `articles.views.hello`

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the `views` class  from the module `articles`. You never imported the articles module its self. there is no need to say `articles.views`. You only use the syntax `module.class` or  `module.function` when just importing the module. But if importing a specific class from a module just use the syntax `class.attribute`. So in your case just say `views.hello` and **not** `articles.views.hello`.

Answer (score 1):

You have already imported articles app, so now you can just point it from there:
`views.hello`